# Running mahout k means clustering command without converting input file to vectors

Tags: vector, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I have a dataset(300MB) on which I wish to run k means clustering using Mahout. The data is in a form of csv which contains only numerical values. Is it still necessary to input the file in vectorized format for the mahout k means command? If not, how can i run the k means command directly on my csv file without converting it to a vector format?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is 300 MB, the answer is **don't use Mahout at all**.

Really ONLY EVER use Mahout when your data no longer fits into memory. Map Reduce is *expensive*, you only want to use it when you can't solve the problem without.

Comment: This was just a sample data, My actual data is quite large. But the problem is that I have only numerical values in the data. Is the mahout k means applicable only for string values, or can I run it successfully for only numerical values as well? Has anyone tried this? Kindly Reply

Comment: K-means computes *means*. It is actually *only* applicable to numerical data. Have you ever read a description of k-means?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/mahout-kmeans-example/ Tells Mahout kmeans is mainly for text processing, if you need to process some numerical data, you need to write some utility functions to write the numerical data into sequence-vector format.

Comment: @SreeVeni So what? Yes, you can run k-means on TF-IDF vectors. But Mahout will still suck; and it will still be awfully slow.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I tried running Kmeans with synthetic data http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-run-k-means-clustering-in-mahout.html How can we supply our own data to run kmeans. Any tutorial regarding the same?

Comment: Don't ask me. I already told you to forget about using Mahout for clustering. It's really really really slow and hard to use.